# Updating database from data in Gridview in VB

Tags: vb.net

This is the code for displaying data from database to gridview....If i am doing any changes in GridView and it has to update in database...I dont know how to do it...Can anyone help me....

```
    Dim DBCONSRT, QRYSTR As String

    Dim strSQL As String

    Dim DBCON, myConn, myCommand, rs As Object

    Dim NoOfRecords As Long
    rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=cpa5k;Data Source=NP1;DSN=NP1;UID=cpa5k;PASSWORD=pass;SDSN=Default;HST=ibslnpb1.sysplex.homedepot.com;PRT=4101;Initial Catalog=QA1MM;"
    myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    myConn.Open(DB_CONNECT_STRING)
    myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
    strSQL = "select * from QA1MM.STRSK_OH FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY with ur;"
    rs.Open(strSQL, myConn)
    Dim myDA As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim myDS As DataSet = New DataSet

    myDA.Fill(myDS, rs, "MyTable")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDS.Tables(0)
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
    myConn.Close()
```

I am trying this method.but it is not working

```
    Dim myDA As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim myDS As DataSet = New DataSet
    myDA.Fill(myDS, rs, "MyTable")
    ds = DataGridView1.DataSource
    myDA.Update(ds)
```

I changed like this:

```
    Dim DBCONSRT, QRYSTR As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim DBCON, myConn, myCommand, rs As Object
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=cpa5k;Data Source=NP1;DSN=NP1;UID=cpa5k;PASSWORD=mexico13;SDSN=Default;HST=ibslnpb1.sysplex.homedepot.com;PRT=4101;Initial Catalog=QA1MM;"
    myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    myConn.Open(DB_CONNECT_STRING)
    myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn

    Dim myDA As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDS As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim dtable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    myDA.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE QA1MM.STRSK_OH set OH_QTY = 10  WHERE SKU_NBR = 108011", myConn)
    '   myDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@OH_QTY", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 15, "OH_QTY")
    '   myDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@SKU_NBR", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 15, "SKU_NBR")
    '   myDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters(0).SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current
    '   myDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters(1).SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current
    dtable = DataGridView1.DataSource
    myDA.Update(dtable)
    myConn.Close()
```

But it is giving error like "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface."

I changed the connection string like:

```
Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data 
Source=NP1;DSN=NP1;SDSN=Default;HST=ibslnpb1.sysplex.homedepot.com;PRT=4101;Integrated 
Security = True;Initial Catalog=QA1MM;
```

Its not working.The error is "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".....Sorry i dont know how to change.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write like follow

```
myConn.Open(DB_CONNECT_STRING) 
myDA.Update(ds.Tables(0))
myConn.Close()
```

EDIT:

Dont take the datasource of DataGridView1 into a dataset, instead take into a DataTable as follows

```
            Dim dtable As New DataTable()
            dtable = DataGridView1.DataSource
```

and update the table with DataAdapter as

```
myConn.Open(DB_CONNECT_STRING) 
myDA.Update(dtable)
myConn.Close()
```

Refer to this link [How to write UpdateCommand to OleDBDataAdapter](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/152185.aspx)

Comment: change the coding as I changed.

Comment: No enable Integrated Security = true in the connection string.

Comment: delete some of your previous comments here to continue the commenting.

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala This is exactly what you shouldn't do. Please continue the discussion in the chat.

Comment: Please edit the relevant information into the question and/or answer, or even post new answers with new details if that is warranted. The comment section of a question/answer is only meant for relevant information regarding the actual post at hand, like mistakes, requests for more details, etc. not for long discussions even though they may be helpful to the people involved. If you need to continue this discussion, consider taking it to a chat room instead.

Comment: @pmr, and Lasse V. Karlsen, surely we will follow your words. Thank you and sorry for not following the rules.

Comment: lets continue our discussion in the chating ok. We should not put more comments here. By the by remove the userid and password, when you enabled the Integrated Security = True.

Comment: I have deleted my previous comments....I changed the connection string and updated in question..can u please tell me what is the mistake.....

Comment: @user1271146, sorry for not helping you correctly. But refer to this mail and read for a while then you come to know how to write your connection string ok. http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        DataSet1.Tables("employee").AcceptChanges()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim cmdbuilder As New OdbcCommandBuilder(odbcadptr)
        i = odbcadptr.Update(odbcds, "customer")
        MsgBox("Updated Rows: " & i)
End Sub
```